# Как в Firebird сделать SELECT из нескольких баз дынных

Tags: sql, firebird

Допустим есть две БД, как выполнить SELECT из обеих БД в IBExpert?

```
SELECT BD1.TableA.*, BD2.TableB.* 
FROM BD1.TableA, BD2.TableB
WHERE BD1.TableA.id = BD2.TableB.id
```

Answer (score 0):

В Firebird есть механизм `EXECUTE STATEMENT … ON EXTERNAL` - выполнение запроса из одной БД к другой.

Но выполнить JOIN с результатом `EXECUTE STATEMENT` не получится. Придется оборачивать его в хранимую процедуру.

Все подробности синтаксиса в документации

https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/firebird-language-reference-30-rus.pdf

https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html

PS не используйте устаревший синтаксис `SELECT … FROM A, B WHERE A.ID = B.ID`. Переходите на нормальные `JOIN`ы